# How to match all character exept dot using regexp in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given string:

```
I can haz kittens. Mmmm. Tasty, tasty kittens.
```

I need get:

```
#without dot
I can haz kittens Mmmm Tasty, tasty kittens
```

I write:

```
string = 'I can haz kittens. Mmmm. Tasty, tasty kittens.'
/[^\.]*/.match(string)
```

Next,I don't know.

Comment: Replace `\.` by `''`(empty string). `str.gsub!(/\./,'')`

Comment: Why use `match` if you need to replace? See https://ideone.com/bE8xO6. What exact output are you trying to get? If you need an array of text chunks consisting of anything but a dot, you may use [`s.scan(/[^.]+/)`](https://ideone.com/R21r8G).

Comment: I am new. Now I will think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need [`String#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-delete):

```
"I can haz kittens. Mmmm. Tasty, tasty kittens.".delete('.')
```

If you really want to use a Regex, you can use [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
"I can haz kittens. Mmmm. Tasty, tasty kittens.".gsub(/\./,'')
```

Comment: ...or use [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-tr): `str.tr('.','')` or `split` then `join`: `str.split('.').join`.

Comment: `tr` is a good tip, probably better than `gsub`. Thanks! No need for creating an array, though.